# two dimensional unique values in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two vectors, one of them stores the width dimension of a set of images and another one the height of these set of images.

I want to use these values as two dimensional vectors [width height] and store them in a matrix. The first line, for instance, keeps the widths and the second line, the heights.

Is it possible to use the unique() function in matlab to return two dimensional unique values? I mean, the values can repeat in one dimension but the two dimensions cannot be the same as another vector?

How to do that in Matlab?

One example: given the following matrix, each column has a two dimensional vector. I want two dimensional unique vectors. The values can repeat in one dimension but not in both.

What I have:

```
[1,2,3,1;
 4,5,6,4]
```

I want as output:

```
[1,2,3;
 4,5,6]
```

Comment: If i understand your question, yes. its possible with `unique` with `rows` option

Comment: give us some two-row matrix and the desired final one, because I can't understand it well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See docs for [`unique`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).

Assuming `widths` and `heights` are column vectors,

```
[C,ia,ic] = unique([widths, heights],'rows')
```

In contrary, if `widths` and `heights` are row vectors,

```
[C,ia,ic] = unique([widths; heights].','rows')
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work.

Suppose I have the matrix[1,2,3,1;4,5,6,4], each column contains two dimensional vectors of (height,width). With the solution you proposed the vector (1,4) will appear twice.

Comment: Since it's looking for unique rows, you have to transpose your matrix. `unique([1,2,3,1;4,5,6,4]', 'rows')` will work.